# css files in django hosted on webfaction

Tags: python, django, webfaction

I'm running django on webfaction, and am having trouble implementing my css files. A sample html file I have is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<h1>
Poll
</h1>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/home/shop/webapps/django/shop/static/index.css" />
<form name="Search bar" action="/search/results/p=1/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
UserId: <input type="text" name="UserId" /><br><br>
<input type="text" name="Keyword" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The exact same file runs fine on my local server, but doesn't work on webfaction. I was wondering if anyone has an idea of whats going wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you referencing this stylesheet  *absolutely*?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/home/shop/webapps/django/shop/static/index.css" />
```

Just refer to the `static` directory, as it takes care of static file loading for you:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/index.css" />
```

If you'd like to know how to set up your media folder, look here: [Django: how do you serve media / stylesheets and link to them within templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446026/django-how-do-you-serve-media-stylesheets-and-link-to-them-within-templates/447991#447991)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So in this example, in my settings.py file I woul have STATIC_URL = '/home/shop/webapps/django/shop' right? I'm not sure why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference a local file. `/home/shop/webapps/django/shop/static/index.css` is your hard drive location.

You need to put it in a media folder and point to it some how. 
[Django deployment via modwsgi](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/)  is how i do it.

**EDIT**

a quick search on webfaction got me: http://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/getting-started.html#serving-static-media

if you put it in a media folder in your application folder you need something like:

```
/home/username/webapps/django_application/media/
```

For standard media/static files