# Allow user to change its picture. Django

Tags: python, django, image

In my app I allow users to have a profile picture. And I would like them to be able to change it. Surprisingly, I didn't find anything on how to accomplish that.

Here is what I tried:

models.py

```
        class UserProfile(FacebookProfileModel):
           user = models.OneToOneField(User)
           profilepic = models.ImageField(upload_to="profilepics/", default="blabla.jpg")
```

my html:

```
       <form method='post' action='{%url myproject.views.changes %}>
       <div class="controls">
       <input type="file" name="image">
       </div>
       <input type="submit">
       </form>
```

my view:

```
      def changes(request):
          if 'image' in request.POST:
             image = request.POST.get('image')
             userprofile.profilepic.url = image
             userprofile.save()
```

When I do that, I get the following error message:

```
       'AttributeError at /my/site/
        can't set attribute'
```

Any idea on how I could accomplish that? Thank you

Comment: This quest and answer should get you started.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example

Comment: Thank you, it does look like it will help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you request a UserProfile object first, then

Looks like you should use

```
image = request.FILES['image']
userprofile.profilepic = image
```

instead of

```
image = request.POST.get('image')
userprofile.profilepic.url = image
```

See [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example), the views.py section, as Jake said

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form. Here is an example of how to update an `ImageField:`

first the update_form.html:

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Update</button>
</form>
```

Then the form:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class EditProfile(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'name', 'avatar')
```

And finally the view:

```py
def user_edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfile(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            if request.FILES.get('avatar', None) != None:
                try:
                    os.remove(request.user.avatar.url)
                except Exception as e:
                    print('Exception in removing old profile image: ', e)
                request.user.avatar = request.FILES['avatar']
                request.user.save()
            return redirect('user:profile', id=request.user.id)
    else:
        form = EditProfile(instance=request.user)
        return render(request, 'user/user-edit.html', {'form': form})
```