# Upload in Django app

Tags: django

I am making a DMS(Document Management System). So, I need to upload various files.
I followed the process as provided in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example).

But unfortunately i am getting an error

```
Exception Type:DatabaseError

Exception Value: no such table: login_document
```

It shows that there is an error in template :-

```
Error during template rendering

In template E:\java\prafuldms\templates\login\list.html, error at line 9
```

The line 9 is

```
{% if documents  %}      ///in list.html
```

What could possibly go wrong? Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I got it.**

In django **advanced** versions, we need to import differently, ie by providing the **relative path**.

In **views.py**  use relative url to import modules

Replace

```
from myproject.myapp.models import Document
from myproject.myapp.forms import DocumentForm
```

By

```
from models import Document
from apps.login.forms import DocumentForm
```

Answer (score 2):

look at documentation examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/)

Comment: Everything is working fine now except when it uploads the documents it does not reverts back to the list of documents uploaded, instead it throws an error NoReverseMatch Exception Value:  Reverse for 'login.views.list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. Any idea on the same?

Answer (score 1):

`documents` apparently is a `QuerySet`. That queryset is evaluated lazily, during template rendering. Unfortunately, it maps to a database table that does not exist.

### Here's what happens:

At template rendering time, Django needs to know whether `documents` is empty or not.

To know that information, Django needs to access the database.

Django makes a query to the database, but the table does not exist.

### Solution

You need to create the database table.
Did you create `models.py`?
Did you run `./manage.py syncdb`?

Comment: Yaa I know that django is querying the database for documents.
I did run the syncdb command. But it still shows the same error.

Comment: Any suggestions... I cant see any error in the code, but still not being able to run it.

Comment: I got it.  In django advanced versions, we need to import differently, ie by providing the relative path.

In views.py import models and forms using relative url.

Comment: Everything is working fine except when it uploads the documents it does not reverts back to the list of documents uploaded, instead it throws an error NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'login.views.list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Any idea on the same?