# Django Executing Python Script

Tags: python, django, csv

i am doing a copy cat with [Need a minimal Django file upload example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example/8542030#8542030)

i changed the view.py with my code to dump the csv file into sqlite database.
i have already created the table in default sqlite database.

```
import sqlite3
import csv
import sys
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from myproject.myapp.models import Document
from myproject.myapp.forms import DocumentForm

def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()


    gfile= csv.reader(open(newdoc))
    gon = sqlite3.connect("database.sqlite")
    gon.text_factory = str
    gon.execute("DELETE FROM abc where rowID > 0 ")
    gon.executemany("insert into abc values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", gfile)
    gon.commit()
    gon.close()*

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myproject.myapp.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'myapp/list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

my code is starting from first introduction of gfile

**Error @ line 20 : Coercing to unicode : need string or buffer, Document Found**
please help

Comment: `newdoc` is a `Document`. `open()` takes a filename, which is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `Document` instance to `open`. Instead you should pass the file, that was uploaded directly to `csv.reader`:

```
gfile = csv.reader(request.FILES['docfile'])
```

Comment: thanks, seems it will work, now it stuck on database table. error: line 23: no such table abc

Comment: thanks a lot, database issues is solved, i gave the full path to database and it works. thanks again for your great guidance