# how to delete object data

Tags: django, python-2.7

i am following [Need a minimal Django file upload example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example/8542030#8542030)

with each upload, list is increasing, how i can delete object data i.e **Document: Document object** manually through python shell

```
>>> from myproject.myapp.models import Document

>>> Document.objects.all()

[<Document: Document object>, <Document: Document object>, <Document: Document object>, <Document: Document object>, <Document: Document object>, 

>>> Document

  <class 'myproject.myapp.models.Document'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete all the objects :-

```
Document.objects.all().delete()
```

Delete objects satisfying some set of filters :-

```
Document.objects.filter(<your_filters>).delete()
```

Deleting objects but also ensuring that your django signals are invoked (if any):

```
for document in Document.objects.filter(<your_filters>):
    document.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
remove(obj1, obj2, ...)
    Removes the specified model objects from the related object set.
```

See documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

Comment: nothing works, i tried different combinations. Document.objects.remove(), remove(Document), remove(Document.objects.all()). please help