# Python get file name and change & save it in variable

Tags: python, django, csv

I am following [Need a minimal Django file upload example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example/8542030#8542030). in view.py there is

```
newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
newdoc.save
```

Let say I upload the file `xyz.csv` which make newdoc or docfile as

`newdoc=xyz.csv` or `docfile=xyz.csv`

I want to do:

```
changedoc = xyz.txt
```

i.e. I  want to remove the extension and give it `.txt` extension

How I can play with it? 
I just need to extract the name only not the file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file name from `request.FILES['docfile'].name`, use `os.path.splitext()` to get the file name without extension:

```
docfile = request.FILES['docfile']
filename = os.path.splitext(docfile.name)[0]
newfilename = 'ok_%s.txt' % filename
```

Comment: thanks a lot, what if i want to add a prefix (ok_)also, ok_docfile.txt

Comment: @ashirnasir you are welcome. Just use `newfilename = 'ok_%s.txt' % filename`, updated the answer.

Comment: thanks, i know it might be irrelivent to the question, but please advice. in view.py (6th line from last) i am trying to replace documents=Document.objects.all() with my newfilename but get error. i am trying to to insted of xyz.csv, link to ok_xyz.txt appears in the 127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/list