# Django File Download

Tags: python, django

i am following this post [Python get file name and change & save it in variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944357/python-get-file-name-and-change-save-it-in-variable/18944389#18944389) and have make some changes which can be seen in this post [Python get file name and change & save it in variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944357/python-get-file-name-and-change-save-it-in-variable/18944389#18944389).

my quest is to show this changed .txt file in the HTML page either manually(inserting the path of the file in list.html) or Dynamically (passing the 'newfilename') to list.html.

too confused, how to give download option on html.
both files are in the same folder. 
please advice

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sqlite3
import csv
import sys
import os
import xlsxwriter
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from myproject.myapp.models import Document
from myproject.myapp.forms import DocumentForm

def list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()
        docfile = request.FILES['docfile']
        filename = os.path.splitext(docfile.name)[0]
        newfilename= 'ok_%s.xlsx' %filename

        gfile= csv.reader(request.FILES['docfile'])
        gon = sqlite3.connect('../myproject/database/database.sqlite3')
        gon.text_factory = str
        gon.execute("DELETE FROM test where rowID > 0 ")
        gon.executemany('insert into test values (?, ?, ?)', gfile)
        gon.commit()
        gon.close()

        conn=sqlite3.connect('../myproject/database/database.sqlite3')
        conn.text_factory = str
        c=conn.cursor()
        ion=c.execute("delete  from test where [Manager id] = 'local'")
        .....
        .....

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('../myproject/media/documents/'+newfilename)
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("no emp")
        worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet("Manager id")


            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myproject.myapp.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    #documents = Document.objects.all().delete()
    #documents = Document.objects.all()
    #mocuments = '../myproject/media/documents/ok_2.xlsx' #this is what i am trying to do
    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    return render_to_response(
        'myapp/list.html', {'documents': documents, 'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: you want to show the contents of the uploaded file in the html?

Comment: yes, this is the ultimate goal, so that user can download it

Comment: is there any way to do it with out changing MODEL and doing some magic through list.html by getting the 'newfilename' value from view.py

Comment: Could you show the contents of your view?

Comment: edited the original post

Comment: i have simulate it manually as "<li><a href="../myproject/media/documents/ok_3.xlsx">Downlod the file it</a></li>
". user have to do Right Click--->Save as to download the file. dump way :p not idea how to do it in proper django way

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your `list.html` template, like this:

```
<ul>
    {% for document in documents %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This assumes `Document.docfile` is a [models.FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield).

Comment: its already there and shows the file name which i upload but i want to add my new created ...xlsx file

Comment: Then, may be you need to extend your `Document` model and add a field that will contain the path of the generated `xlsx` file.

Comment: you mean add a new column to database manually and pass it through view.py to list.html

Comment: Look: you are saving an uploaded document in a `Document` model. Why don't have an additional field in the model, like `reportfile`, where you will store the path to the newly generated file. Then in the template, you can refer to it as `document.reportfile`. What do you think?

Comment: am a newb sorry if argu much. now i have change the model and force a new table in database with name of mocument. success is that i am able to store the file name of newly created xlsx file in DB in myapp_mocument. now am stuck again with list.html. as my file name is already in database i should show in html but no.

Comment: i have add in html...{% for mocument in mocuments %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ mocument.docfile.url }}">{{ mocument.mocfile.name }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}

Comment: is there a way in django to call a record from Database directly. i have the my new xlsx name in Database now. what can stop us now

Comment: @ashirnasir please, show what you've done so far (include in the question or create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/)). Thanks.