# os.path.split, changing file name with out compromising the Path

Tags: python, django

i have followed [Python get file name and change & save it in variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944357/python-get-file-name-and-change-save-it-in-variable/18944389?noredirect=1#comment27975063_18944389). which work fine and change the file name as required.

but now i am facing problem with path where the file is getting saved. as the file is getting saved in "**media/ok_abc.txt**" whereas it should be **media/documents/ok_abc.txt**

e.g.

docfile = /media/documents/abc.csv
after applaying below instruction

```
filename = os.path.splitext(docfile.name)[0]
newfilename = 'ok_%s.txt' % filename
```

am able to change the file name but the path is getting reduced as **/media/ok_abc.txt**, it should be **/media/documents/abc.txt**

how i can change the file name with out compromising on the Path

Answer (score 25):

Extract the directory from the full file path, and later add it back.

```
path, filename = os.path.split(docfile)
filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
newfilename = 'ok_%s.txt' % filename
newpath = os.path.join(path, newfilename)
```

Comment: thanks. sounds dummy but now i will be using newpath instead of newfile for further processing/following code. right?

Comment: newpath is the full path while newfilename is just a filename. Adapt as it fits.