# How copy file and give prefix now date with shutil

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want give prefix for file, but i have errors, can u help me?

```
 import shutil, datetime
 v = datetime.datetime.now()
 x = v.strftime('%Y.%m.%d.')
 shutil.copyfile('C:\\users\\v.korolev\\desktop\\dev\\python\\zxc.txt', x+'C:\\users\\v.korolev\\desktop\\dev\\python\\old\\zxc.txt')
```

Comment: You are appending the `x` as prefix to absolute path which makes no sense, You need to append `x` to `zxc` in the file path I guess, for that you must use `os.split()` to split the path and then select the last element, then modify it the way you want, and reconstruct the path using `os.join()`

Comment: *but i have errors* You should always include the error you are getting when you ask a question.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\v.korolev\Desktop\dev\python\copy\copy25.py", line 4, in <module>
    shutil.copyfile('C:\\users\\v.korolev\\desktop\\dev\\python\\zxc.txt', x+'C:\\users\\v.korolev\\desktop\\dev\\python\\old\\zxc.txt')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: '2017.02.03.C:\\users\\v.korolev\\desktop\\dev\\python\\old\\zxc.txt'

Comment: @ZdaR Can u help me with this code. I understand you, but i can't realize this.

Comment: Possible dupe of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950668/os-path-split-changing-file-name-with-out-compromising-the-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import shutil, datetime, os
v = datetime.datetime.now()
x = v.strftime('%Y.%m.%d.')
file = "C:\\users\\v.korolev\\desktop\\dev\\python\\zxc.txt"
shutil.copyfile(file, "C:\\users\\v.korolev\\desktop\\dev\\python\\old\\%szxc.txt" % x)
```

I realize it! Thanks you for help