# add prefix from sub-directory to the name of file

Tags: python

Can You give me tips how I can add to copied files name the prefix comes from name of sub-directory for example

this is my source dir `'/home/ip/input/IP10/STAT-IP_202211151610_7428/some_files'`

```
import os
import glob
import shutil


for f in glob.glob('/opt/data/input/IP10/**/*.*', recursive=True):
    shutil.copy(f, '/opt/data/input/IP10_for_decoder/copy/')
```

then I need to get file name after it copied: STAT-IP_202211151610_7428_some_files ?

Comment: why does `some_files` change to `same_files`? Are some files renamed to the same name?

Comment: it was a typo, and it has been already fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is definitely a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019646/how-copy-file-and-give-prefix-now-date-with-shutil).

Using `os` is fine, but my preference is pathlib's Path module - it handles windows and linux / unix paths real well, so makes for easy cross platform utilization. It has various methods already built into it, so you "don't have to" import `glob` and `os` modules for moving files, checking if they exist, etc:

With the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42021440/3155240) from the question linked above, we can do this:

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

path = Path(r"/opt/data/input/IP10/")
abs_path = path.absolute().parent # the path to the `Path` directory's parent directory

# there is a glob method as well.
# rglob is the recursive method.
for f in path.rglob('**/*.*'):
    dir_name = f.parent.stem # the parent directory's name
    name = f.with_name(f"{dir_name}_{f.name}").name # the new name of the file
    shutil.copy(f, f'{abs_path}/IP10_for_decoder/copy/{name}')
```

Some nice examples of what can be done with Path:

```
path = Path("./kansas.png")

path.stem # -> kansas
path.name # -> kansas.png
path.suffix # -> .png - if no "." in the filename, this will return an empty string
path.with_suffix(".jpg") # -> kansas.jpg
path.with_stem("texas") # -> texas.png
path.with_name("texas.jpg") # -> texas.jpg


path.absolute() # -> returns "/opt/data/input/IP10/kansas.png"
path.exists() # -> returns a boolean if it exists
path.parent # -> on absolute paths returns the full path to the parent directory
path.unlink() # deletes the file
path.touch() # "touches" the file
# replace and rename are a little hard to distinguish the difference between, imo, but both return a new path
path = path.replace(Path("/new/location/new_name.jpg"))
path = path.rename("new_file_name.jpg") # will rename the file
```

I thought there was a copy method for pathlib's Path, but [nope](https://bugs.python.org/issue24229).

There are a myriad of other operations - `.parts` splits the path into a list of directories and the filename that make up the path, you can read and write bytes and text to and from a file, `.chmod` a file or directory, and so on. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Comment: Yes it looks so good but something goes wrong 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/data/input/IP10_for_decoder/copy//opt/data/input/input_IP10'

Comment: @stanny Okay, this should work now. If not, I will check in the morning.

Comment: Update: had to change `dir_name = path.parent.stem` to `dir_name = f.parent.stem`.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```py
import os, glob, shutil

rootpath = os.path.join("..", "Desktop", "*")

for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(rootpath, 'IP10/**/*.*'), recursive=True):
    last_two = os.path.join(*f.split(os.sep)[-2:]) # get two last path items. I.e. dir/file.txt
    shutil.copy(f, os.path.join(rootpath, 'IP10_for_decoder/copy/', last_two)) # add last two to end
```

This is assuming that within the `IP10` folder you only have one directory and one file. If there are directory trees then you'd need a slightly different approach.

EDIT: Fix `os.path.join` input convention

Comment: yeap but anyway thanks for above

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copy.py", line 16, in <module>
    rootpath = os.path.join(["opt", "data", "input"])
  File "/opt/pypy/lib/pypy3.9/posixpath.py", line 76, in join
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Comment: My mistake, the `os.path.join` function takes in multiple args, not a list of items. I edited the answer to fix this. Hopefully the new version helps.

Comment: @stanny do you have an update on this question? Did the edit of my answer I provided end up working for you?

Comment: Many Thanks for finding out the solution.

Comment: Great! You're very welcome. If this solves your issue you can mark the answer as the solution so that the thread can be closed