# How to upload an image in django web application?

Tags: python, html, django, image-upload

I need to ask the user to upload an image on a django web app but i don't know how to start and what to write in views.py or models.py or settings.py
I searched for answers but didn't get full or step-wise answer to this (I am new to django)
I have given MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in the settings.py but need help in further implementation

Comment: you may start from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example

Answer (score 4):

Download https://github.com/doph/minimal-django-file-upload-example, as suggested here: [Need a minimal Django file upload example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example)

it's a basic Django project with single app using `media/` directory for uploads.