# form.is_valid() returns false (django)

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am a bit new to django. Im trying to send a file over to another server once it is chosen in upload, but is `form.is_valid()` always return false would not let me enter `if`

`views.py`-

```
def sent(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SendFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print "form is made"
        print form.errors
        if form.is_valid():
            print "form is valid"
            new_song = Song(songfile= request.FILES['songfile'])
            new_song.save()
            print "new song is made and saved"
            l = List()
            #cd = form.cleaned_data                                                                                                                   
            #SENDS THE FILE TO SERVER GIVEN PATH
            l.all_files(new_song.songfile.path)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('get_files.views.sent'))
        else:
            print "form is not valid"
    else:
        form = SendFileForm()

    songs = Song.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('sent.html', {'songs': songs,'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

`sent.html` template-

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <p style="color: red;">
        Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
    </p>
{% endif %}

<form action={% url "sent" %} method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.songfile.label_tag }} {{ form.songfile.help_text }}</p>
        <p>
            <!--{{ form.songfile.errors }}-->
            {{ form.songfile }}
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>
```

`forms.py`-

```
class SendFileForm(forms.Form):
    path = forms.CharField()
    songfile = forms.FileField(label='Select a music file',help_text='max. 4 megabytes')
```

I have searched up many forums and not able to solve the problem. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you add your ``forms.py`` file content?

Comment: Your form classes should be named using ``CamelCase``, e.g. ``SendFileForm``.

Comment: Yea sure I will add my `forms.py`

Comment: It should match the form-naming convention now. But do have any hints as to why it the form is not being validated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every field in form are required by default (`required=True`). Form submitted without information in required field is not valid. You can add `path` field to your form in template and it must be filled or you can make path not required:

```
class SendFileForm(forms.Form):
    path = forms.CharField(required=False)
    ...
```

or

```
<form action={% url "sent" %} method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
            {{ form.songfile }}
            {{ form.path }}
...
</form>
```

Comment: Ah I didn't notice the `path` field at all! It was before I implemented the upload feature. It all works now, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

**Note:-** This answer is Only to help you in debugging the code.

You can print form errors in your views directly.

```
class YourFormView(generic.edit.CreateView):

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = YourForm(request.POST)
    for field in form:
        print("Field Error:", field.name,  field.errors)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no `path` input in your template. Your `request.POST` contains incomplete data thats why your form is not valid.

This is missing in your template:

```
{{ form.path }}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `path` input in template? I am following this example (the answer)- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example

Comment: isnt the `url 'sent'` suppose to specify where to send back the data? and where is `GET` being used?

Comment: I see what you were trying to get at now. I added the upload feature after adding `path`. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

In addition to laxmikant's answer, one more way to debug is get the errors like below,

```
class YourFormView(generic.edit.CreateView):

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = YourForm(request.POST)
    print(form.errors)
```

**Note: This is only debugging technique**