# Saving formset filefield fails

Tags: python, django, forms, file-upload, formset

Trying to save a fileField in a formset, but the debug returns UploadPdfFormSet' object has no attribute 'save'. Feel like the documentation around handling files in formsets are lacking. Anything you guys could help me with?

forms.py

```
    from django import forms

class UploadPdf(forms.Form):
    docfiles = forms.FileField(label='Browse')

class UploadPdfUrl(forms.Form):
    docurl = forms.URLField(label='Address')
```

views.py

```
    def upload(request):    
        UploadPdfFormSet = formset_factory(UploadPdf)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            formsetFile = UploadPdfFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)     
            if formsetFile.is_valid():
                instances = formsetFile.save
                for form in instances:
                    form.save()

                return HttpResponse('yey')
        else:
            formsetFile = UploadPdfFormSet()
            formURL = UploadPdfUrl

        return render(request, 'pdfchecker/index.html', {
            'formsetFile': formsetFile, 'formURL': formURL,
            })



UPDATE: New view.py file which successfully saves file:

def upload(request):

    UploadPdfFormSet = formset_factory(UploadPdf)
    handleUploadPdfFormSet = modelformset_factory(handle_UploadPdf)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formsetFile = UploadPdfFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        formsetHandle = handleUploadPdfFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formsetFile.is_valid():
            formsetHandle.save()

            return HttpResponse('yey')
    else:
        formsetFile = UploadPdfFormSet()
        formURL = UploadPdfUrl

    return render(request, 'pdfchecker/index.html', {
        'formsetFile': formsetFile, 'formURL': formURL,
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are referring to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset) example of the documentation. But this example is all about [ModelFormsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseModelFormSet), not the regular formset you are using. The save method doesn't make sense here.  So you have two options:

- use ModelFormsets (of course if there are models in your app that correspond to UploadPdf form)
- (which is more likely) do the stuff with the formset cleaned_data manually. Like in [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates) example.

Comment: Seems like i didn't really understand forms properly. I get that you have to use the models to save the files now. Let's say i have this in my models.py:

from django.db import models

class handle_UploadPdf(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='.')

Do you know how do i proceed with formsets? I've made it with normal forms, but when i introduce formsets everything just gets a bit harder i guess.

Comment: @Koronag But what is a purpose of having this model (handle_UploadPdf)?

Comment: I want to save the file to a specific location. As you can see now it is just marked as a ".", but i really want a specific URL as the destination.

I followed this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example
But that one only accounts for regular forms, and not formsets. So i'm kinda confused.

Comment: @Koronag But how do you use the data saved into this model? Is the model somehow connected to any of your other models?

Comment: Not really. Thing is, in the example you just upload the files directly to the media storage and then generate date, time etc. What i want to do is upload the file to an external url. But it seems like this is rather decided in settings py. I've updated the view with a solution that now atleast saves the file.

views.py

Comment: My point is that there is no need to create model just to handle uploading of arbitrary files. Instead you could handle them manually like described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: Instead of creating a model i just create a function which handles it? To be honest im a bit confused.

Comment: @Koronag If you don't really need the data about uploaded files in the DB, than you don't need a model. In this case it's better to handle uploaded files manually, not using a fictive model.

Comment: I see. Then i have no idea how to save the file properly. Dont really get the examples in the django ducmentation tbh.