# How to access uploaded files in Django?

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I followed the uploading example for django here:

[Minimal Django File Upload Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example)

Now I want display the uploaded file (.jpg or .pdf) in the browser. By clicking on the link the browser opens the URL: localhost:8000/media/documents/2014/08/04/test1.jpg
and Django throws an error: The current URL, media/documents/2014/08/04/test1.jpg, didn't match any of my defined urls.

How can I change the url-settings for my media files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable django to serve static files for you. Docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ .
This in particular https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development .

Comment: ok I added `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`to the urls. Now it is working so far... Now I have to figure out how to use sub-directories...

Comment: @work.b for sub-directories is the same, just use your MEDIA URL/you-new-subdirectory

Comment: Ok I solved the problem. I had a mistake in my MEDIA_ROOT path... Now it is working fine!