# How can I upload media files with Django Tinymce-filbrowser?

Tags: python, django, tinymce, file-browser

I´m using django-tinymce  and django-tinymce filebrowser to upload images to the text editor. The images work perfectly but when I want to upload a media file I get a 404 error.
[image]

Is there any way I can solve this and make the upload of media available? The images work so I think it just might be a matter of redirecting the URL somehow.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Static files needs to be handled differently in django [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example) is complete solution to handle file uploads in django it might be helpful