# django-summernote image upload

Tags: django, summernote

I recently implemented [django-summernote](https://github.com/lqez/django-summernote) with my forms, which works well for text. However, I struggle to get exactly how image upload works. Does anyone have some input on how it is done?

**Problem**

When choosing an image from file with Summernote, the *Insert Image* button is deactivated (works fine for image links). I did not write a custom 'upload_to' function, but as I get it, this is already done in django-summernote.

**Details**

1. Installed django-summernote according to documentation.
2. Added summernote to urls and in INSTALLED_APPS
3. Added summernote to my form field

   directions = forms.CharField(
       widget=SummernoteInplaceWidget(attrs={'maxlength':'4000'}),
       required=False,
   )
4. Also added some config in SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG (settings.py)

   ```
   SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
       'iframe': True,

       'airMode': True,

       'width': '100%',
       'height': '300',

         'toolbar': [
           # ['style', ['style']],
           ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'strikethrough', 'clear']],
           # ['fontname', ['fontname']],
           ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
           # ['color', ['color']],
           ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
           ['height', ['height']],
           ['table', ['table']],
           ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video', 'hr']],
           ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview']],
           ['help', ['help']],
         ], }
   ```

Do I also have to write my own backend for attachments (images)? STATIC_URL and MEDIA_URL is defined in my settings.py, if that matters for this issue.

**Update November 29th 2014:**

When choosing an image, the following error is given in the console: "undefined is not a function", which is related to

```
imageInput.fileupload();
```

The "Insert Image" button is disabled.

As my project is in developing mode, I have *DEBUG=True* in my settings.

My urls look like:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
  url(r'^summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
  ) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and *Media_root* and *Media_url* are set to:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'media',)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I use picture uploads outside django-summernote with these settings.

Feels like I am missing something, but can´t see what.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`django-summernote` shipped with backend support for image uploading out of box. So you don't have to write your own backend for it. `MEDIA_ROOT` or `MEDIA_URL` settings may have wrong value for uploading - permission problem or not valid path.

Run django project with `runserver` and please check the browser console(inspect) and python console after trying to upload an image.

And also refer [Need a minimal Django file upload example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example) for handling files on django project.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @lqez. Unfortunately, I still cannot make it work. Further details are added to the original post. Would you mind have a quick look at it? When I select an image from file, the above error occur.