# Uploading image from Imagefield in django

Tags: python, django, django-file-upload, django-media

I am new to Django.I have the following code on my `html` file:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<form method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
<input type="file" name="file">
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
{{file}}
<img class="hl" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}photos/abc.png" /></a>
<img class="hl" src="{% static 'blog/images/sec.png' %}" /></a>
```

and my `views.py` for the above code is:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' in request.POST:
            f = request.POST['file']
            a = MyUser(email="frt@wer.com", date_of_birth=date.today())
            a.photo.save('somename.png', File(open(f, 'r')))
            a.save()
            context = {'file': f}
            return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Now browsers do not return the absolute path of the file from user's local device, it just gathers filename because ofsome `security issues` but `a.photo.save('somename.png', File(open(f, 'r')))` this part of my code needs absolute path of user local device that is something like `/home/abc/Pictures/sec.png` all i get is `sec.png` and hence i am unable to upload.

From `python manage.py shell`:

```
>>>a = MyUser(email="frt@wer.com", date_of_birth=date.today())
>>>a.photo.save('somename.png', File(open('/home/abc/Pictures/sec.png', 'r')))
>>>a.save()
```

This works fine. Is there some workaround. I dont want to use `Form`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that if you want to allow for a file upload that you use a File form rather than a workaround. A simple and very succinct example can be found here:

[Need a minimal Django file upload example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example)

Comment: i looked into it..it looks great..i am trying it out.