# Django: upload image to form

Tags: python, html, django, image, forms

I am new to Django and am writing my first app.  It is simple and you use a form to add a new "client".  One of the fields is an ImageField, and after inputting the image, and submitting the form, the image disappears and is not associated with that client.

I've tried messing around with the request.FILES command, but nothing seems to work, and have added enctype="multipart/form-data" to the html page.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from address_book.models import Client, UserProfile

class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Name: ")
    phone = forms.IntegerField(help_text="Phone Number: ")
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Address: ", required=False)
    desired_weight = forms.IntegerField(help_text="Desired Weight: ")
    picture = forms.ImageField(help_text="Upload image: ", required=False)
    start_weight = forms.IntegerField(help_text="Start Weight: ")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    likes = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
    comments = forms.CharField(max_length=500, help_text="Comments: ", required=False)

    # An inline class to provide additional information on the form.
    class Meta:
        # Provide an association between the ModelForm and a model
        model = Client
        fields = ('name', 'phone', 'address', 'desired_weight', 'start_weight', 'picture',)

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('nickname',)
#        fields = ('website', 'picture')
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from address_book.forms import ClientForm, UserForm, UserProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from address_book.models import Client



def index(request):

    client_list = Client.objects.all().order_by('name')
    # Construct a dictionary to pass to the template engine as its context.
    # Note the key boldmessage is the same as {{ boldmessage }} in the template!
    context_dict = {'clients': client_list}

    # Return a rendered response to send to the client.
    # We make use of the shortcut function to make our lives easier.
    # Note that the first parameter is the template we wish to use.

    return render(request, 'address_book/index.html', context_dict)

def add_client(request):
    # A HTTP POST?
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClientForm(request.POST)

        # Have we been provided with a valid form?
        if form.is_valid():
            # Save the new category to the database.
            form.save(commit=True)

            # Now call the index() view.
            # The user will be shown the homepage.

            if 'picture' in request.FILES:
                form.picture =request.FILES['picture']

            form.save()

            return index(request)
        else:
            # The supplied form contained errors - just print them to the terminal.
            print form.errors
    else:
        # If the request was not a POST, display the form to enter details.
        form = ClientForm()

    # Bad form (or form details), no form supplied...
    # Render the form with error messages (if any).
    return render(request, 'address_book/add_client.html', {'form': form})

def client(request, client_name_slug):

    # Create a context dictionary which we can pass to the template rendering engine.
    context_dict = {}

    try:
        # Can we find a category name slug with the given name?
        # If we can't, the .get() method raises a DoesNotExist exception.
        # So the .get() method returns one model instance or raises an exception.
        client = Client.objects.get(slug=client_name_slug)
        context_dict['client_name'] = client.name
        context_dict['client_name_slug'] = client_name_slug
        context_dict['client_phone'] = client.phone
        context_dict['client_address'] = client.address
        context_dict['desired_weight'] = client.desired_weight
        context_dict['start_weight'] = client.start_weight
        context_dict['comments'] = client.comments
        context_dict['picture'] = client.picture 

        # Retrieve all of the associated pages.
        # Note that filter returns >= 1 model instance.
#        pages = Page.objects.filter(category=category)

        # Adds our results list to the template context under name pages.
#        context_dict['pages'] = pages
        # We also add the category object from the database to the context dictionary.
        # We'll use this in the template to verify that the category exists.
        context_dict['client'] = client
    except Client.DoesNotExist:
        # We get here if we didn't find the specified category.
        # Don't do anything - the template displays the "no category" message for us.
        pass

    # Go render the response and return it to the client.
    print context_dict
    return render(request, 'address_book/client.html', context_dict)

def register(request):

    # A boolean value for telling the template whether the registration was successful.
    # Set to False initially. Code changes value to True when registration succeeds.
    registered = False

    # If it's a HTTP POST, we're interested in processing form data.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Attempt to grab information from the raw form information.
        # Note that we make use of both UserForm and UserProfileForm.
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        # If the two forms are valid...
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            # Save the user's form data to the database.
            user = user_form.save()

            # Now we hash the password with the set_password method.
            # Once hashed, we can update the user object.
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            # Now sort out the UserProfile instance.
            # Since we need to set the user attribute ourselves, we set commit=False.
            # This delays saving the model until we're ready to avoid integrity problems.
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            # Did the user provide a profile picture?
            # If so, we need to get it from the input form and put it in the UserProfile model.
            if 'picture' in request.FILES:
                profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']

            # Now we save the UserProfile model instance.
            profile.save()

            # Update our variable to tell the template registration was successful.
            registered = True

        # Invalid form or forms - mistakes or something else?
        # Print problems to the terminal.
        # They'll also be shown to the user.
        else:
            print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors

    # Not a HTTP POST, so we render our form using two ModelForm instances.
    # These forms will be blank, ready for user input.
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    # Render the template depending on the context.
    return render(request,
            'address_book/register.html',
            {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered} )

def user_login(request):

    # If the request is a HTTP POST, try to pull out the relevant information.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Gather the username and password provided by the user.
        # This information is obtained from the login form.
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        # Use Django's machinery to attempt to see if the username/password
        # combination is valid - a User object is returned if it is.
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        # If we have a User object, the details are correct.
        # If None (Python's way of representing the absence of a value), no user
        # with matching credentials was found.
        if user:
            # Is the account active? It could have been disabled.
            if user.is_active:
                # If the account is valid and active, we can log the user in.
                # We'll send the user back to the homepage.
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/address_book/')
            else:
                # An inactive account was used - no logging in!
                return HttpResponse("Your 3010 account is disabled.")
        else:
            # Bad login details were provided. So we can't log the user in.
            print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")

    # The request is not a HTTP POST, so display the login form.
    # This scenario would most likely be a HTTP GET.
    else:
        # No context variables to pass to the template system, hence the
        # blank dictionary object...
        return render(request, 'address_book/login.html', {})

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    # Since we know the user is logged in, we can now just log them out.
    logout(request)

    # Take the user back to the homepage.
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/address_book/')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Client(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
        phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        desired_weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        start_weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='/address_book/profile_pics', blank=True)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
        comments = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                self.slug = slugify(self.name)
                super(Client, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
#    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
#    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

    # Override the __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

add_client.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}Add a Client{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}

<h1>Add a Client</h1>

<form id="ClientForm" method="post" action="/address_book/add_client/" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.help_text }}
        {{ field }}
        <br />
        <br />
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Client" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

client.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% load easy_maps_tags %}

{% load addressbook_extras %}

{% block title %}{{ client_name }}{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}
    <h1>{{ client_name }}</h1>
        <li>Phone: {{ client_phone }} </li>
        <li>Address: {{ client_address }} </li>
        <li>Start Weight: {{ start_weight }} </li>
        <li> Desired Weight: {{ desired_weight }} </li>
        <li> Comments: {{ comments }} </li>
        {% if picture %}
        <img src="{ picture }" alt="Client Photo">
        {% else %}
        <li> No image uploaded </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% if client_address|address_test != None %}
            {% easy_map client_address 400 400 %}
        {% else %}
            <strong> Invalid address </strong>
        {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Address Book</title>
    </head>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h1>Hello {{ user.username }}!</h1>
        {% else %}
        <h1>Please login below</h1>
        {% endif %}
    <body>
        {% block body_block %}{% endblock %}
    </body>

    <h2> Need to make changes? </h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Go home</a></li>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'add_client' %}">Add new client</a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>      
        <li><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register here</a></li>  
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I seems that you forgot to pass the request.FILES to your form.

Try this :

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClientForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Here is an excellent example of file upload with django :
[Need a minimal Django file upload example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
<img src="{ picture }" alt="Client Photo">
```

You should use double brackets *and* the `url()` method as in:

```
<img src="{{ picture.url }}" alt="Client Photo">
```

`ImageField`s are extended `FieldFile`s and you can access the relative url using [url() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url)

Comment: That might be an error, but doesn't fix the problem.  WhenI upload the image, the image doesn't remain.  If I have the shell print out the context dictionary, it contains all fields as they have been entered, but picture remains empty.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to manually set the `profile.picture` field. You don't have to do it as `form.save` automatically saves the uploaded images: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model

Comment: okay, this seems to fix it, but it displays a broken image icon, rather than the image when I try to open it

Comment: What do you see in the `img src="..."` when you view the HTML source in your web browser?

Comment: also, it isn't saving the file to the specified location in the model which is why I think my above comment is occurring

Comment: it shows the correct location, only nothing is at that location

Comment: You should change `upload_to='/address_book/profile_pics'` to `upload_to='address_book/profile_pics'` (remove the slash) because it has to be a path relative to MEDIA_ROOT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71714/discussion-between-jeremy-thomas-and-selcuk).