# How to browse local files from Django and store the file information

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, file-upload, filereader

I'm new to Django and want to give a user the ability to browse through their local files and "upload" them. However I do not actually want to store their files on my database, I only want to get the filename, path, memory etc of the file the user has selected. I have read through [Need a minimal Django file upload example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example), and many more sites, but everything talks about uploading a file. Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only interface to local files available in a web browser is the File-picker, as if to select a file for upload. But, you don't have to upload the files! You can work with them in Javascript instead. See for example's Mozilla's documentation on "[Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)".

Note that the Javascript `File` objects you get back have `name`, `size`, and [MIME] `type` properties.

Your client-side Javascript could poke these into a form, that the user then submits to your server-side Django application. Or, the client-side Javascript could put them into an AJAX action that submits them to the server-side Django application.