# Django Rest Framework image upload and get image

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a use case where an angular front end will need to submit image and Django  Rest Framework API will need to save it to filesystem during image upload calls. During image download scenario the image will need also be served up from filesystem. 
If someone already figured out this usecase please post it.  Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django REST framework provides [an `ImageField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#imagefield) that can handle the uploading of images [using Django's file upload handlers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/). So you might be interested in learning how it is done in Django first: [Need a minimal Django file upload example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871730/359284)