# Django file upload form with single button

Tags: python, django, forms, file, upload

I need code snippet of django file upload form with single button. I've found excellent implementation of [minimal-django-file-upload-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example), but there are two buttons: "Browse" and "Upload". Is there a way to submit the file immediately after browsing without clicking "Upload" button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JavaScript/jQuery:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" class="autosubmit" />
</form>
```

And then apply the following:

```
$('form .autosubmit').on('change', function() {
   this.form.submit();
});
```

Without jQuery it's very similar, you'll just need to use `EventTarget.addEventListener`.