# Django Add first image

Tags: django, image, imagefield

I have some problem with adding image to my project.

Settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/static/uploads'
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
```

Model:

```
class UserLogo(models.Model):
upload_path = '/static/uploads'
logo = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Logo", upload_to=upload_path)
```

Form:

```
class LogoUploadForm(forms.Form):
logo = forms.ImageField(label='Logo')
```

View:

```
def add_user_logo(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LogoUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        user_logo = UserLogo
        user_logo.logo = form.cleaned_data['logo']
        user_logo.save()
return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_settings/show_user/')
```

Template:

```
<form id="logo_upload_form" role="form" action="/user_settings/add_user_logo/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   {% csrf_token %}
   {% if logo_upload_form %}
       <table class="table table-striped">
       <tbody>
       <tr>
       <td>{{logo_upload_form.logo.label</td>
       <td{{logo_upload_form.logo}}</td>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
       </table>
   {% endif %}
    </form>
```

I choose img and submit but img dont want to add. I cant find img file in my 'upload_to' place.

Comment: There are examples with file upload it is similar to uploading images. I recommend looking at it and understand it carefully. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example)

Answer (score 0):

Django appends the upload_to path to MEDIA_ROOT to find the location to save your file. According to your code it will be **/static/uploads/static/upload/**

Also the MEDIA_ROOT should be an absolute path like /home/username/path/ (in unix) or C:/path/ (in windows).

Comment: I changed to full path but nothing change

Comment: Ok works, i can add images, problem was in view ( forgot change one line). But now i have problem because i want to make thumbnail. I can`t use 'user_logo.thumbnail((128, 128))' because ''UserLogo' object has no attribute 'thumbnail'' @Tony Joseph

Comment: Because user_logo does not have an attribute named 'thumbnail'. user_logo is a model object. If you are trying to generate thumbnails from images, consider using pillow. [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/)

Answer (score 0):

modify your MEDIA_ROOT as follows:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/uploads/')
```

**open urls.py file:**

Add the following:

```
...
from django.conf import settings
...

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   ...    
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I edited MEDIA_ROOT but everything works fine without this '+static' in URL file.