# Django file upload with FTP backend

Tags: python, django, file-upload, ftp, remote-server

I want to upload my files based on the example [Need a minimal Django file upload example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example), however I want to store the files not locally, but on another server with the use of FTP.

I have been trying to get [this](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/ftp.py) code to work, which looks simple enough, but I keep getting  `ImportError: No module named FTPStorage` when I run   `python manage.py runserver`

I have looked at multiple repos and searched this site but to no avail. I suppose it's a fairly simple task, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks.

**Folder structure**

[image: folder_structure]

**settings.py**

```
"""

Django settings for myproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '<The very long super secret key>'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myproject.myapp',
    'storages',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myproject', 'myapp', 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.ftp.FTPStorage'
FTP_STORAGE_LOCATION = 'ftp://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/[path]'
```

**models.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from FTPStorage import FTPStorage

fs = FTPStorage()
class FTPTest(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='srv/ftp/', storage=fs)

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
```

**ftp.py**

```
# FTP storage class for Django pluggable storage system.
# Author: Rafal Jonca <jonca.rafal@gmail.com>
# License: MIT
# Comes from http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1269/
#
# Usage:
#
# Add below to settings.py:
# FTP_STORAGE_LOCATION = '[a]ftp://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/[path]'
#
# In models.py you can write:
# from FTPStorage import FTPStorage
# fs = FTPStorage()
# class FTPTest(models.Model):
#     file = models.FileField(upload_to='a/b/c/', storage=fs)

import os
from datetime import datetime
import ftplib

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.base import File
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured

from storages.compat import urlparse, BytesIO, Storage


class FTPStorageException(Exception):
    pass


class FTPStorage(Storage):
    """FTP Storage class for Django pluggable storage system."""

    def __init__(self, location=settings.FTP_STORAGE_LOCATION,
                 base_url=settings.MEDIA_URL):
        self._config = self._decode_location(location)
        self._base_url = base_url
        self._connection = None

    def _decode_location(self, location):
        """Return splitted configuration data from location."""
        splitted_url = urlparse.urlparse(location)
        config = {}

        if splitted_url.scheme not in ('ftp', 'aftp'):
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                'FTPStorage works only with FTP protocol!'
            )
        if splitted_url.hostname == '':
            raise ImproperlyConfigured('You must at least provide hostname!')

        if splitted_url.scheme == 'aftp':
            config['active'] = True
        else:
            config['active'] = False
        config['path'] = splitted_url.path
        config['host'] = splitted_url.hostname
        config['user'] = splitted_url.username
        config['passwd'] = splitted_url.password
        config['port'] = int(splitted_url.port)

        return config

    def _start_connection(self):
        # Check if connection is still alive and if not, drop it.
        if self._connection is not None:
            try:
                self._connection.pwd()
            except ftplib.all_errors:
                self._connection = None

        # Real reconnect
        if self._connection is None:
            ftp = ftplib.FTP()
            try:
                ftp.connect(self._config['host'], self._config['port'])
                ftp.login(self._config['user'], self._config['passwd'])
                if self._config['active']:
                    ftp.set_pasv(False)
                if self._config['path'] != '':
                    ftp.cwd(self._config['path'])
                self._connection = ftp
                return
            except ftplib.all_errors:
                raise FTPStorageException(
                    'Connection or login error using data %s'
                    % repr(self._config)
                )

    def disconnect(self):
        self._connection.quit()
        self._connection = None

    def _mkremdirs(self, path):
        pwd = self._connection.pwd()
        path_splitted = path.split('/')
        for path_part in path_splitted:
            try:
                self._connection.cwd(path_part)
            except:
                try:
                    self._connection.mkd(path_part)
                    self._connection.cwd(path_part)
                except ftplib.all_errors:
                    raise FTPStorageException(
                        'Cannot create directory chain %s' % path
                    )
        self._connection.cwd(pwd)
        return

    def _put_file(self, name, content):
        # Connection must be open!
        try:
            self._mkremdirs(os.path.dirname(name))
            pwd = self._connection.pwd()
            self._connection.cwd(os.path.dirname(name))
            self._connection.storbinary('STOR ' + os.path.basename(name),
                                        content.file,
                                        content.DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE)
            self._connection.cwd(pwd)
        except ftplib.all_errors:
            raise FTPStorageException('Error writing file %s' % name)

    def _open(self, name, mode='rb'):
        remote_file = FTPStorageFile(name, self, mode=mode)
        return remote_file

    def _read(self, name):
        memory_file = BytesIO()
        try:
            pwd = self._connection.pwd()
            self._connection.cwd(os.path.dirname(name))
            self._connection.retrbinary('RETR ' + os.path.basename(name),
                                        memory_file.write)
            self._connection.cwd(pwd)
            return memory_file
        except ftplib.all_errors:
            raise FTPStorageException('Error reading file %s' % name)

    def _save(self, name, content):
        content.open()
        self._start_connection()
        self._put_file(name, content)
        content.close()
        return name

    def _get_dir_details(self, path):
        # Connection must be open!
        try:
            lines = []
            self._connection.retrlines('LIST ' + path, lines.append)
            dirs = {}
            files = {}
            for line in lines:
                words = line.split()
                if len(words) < 6:
                    continue
                if words[-2] == '->':
                    continue
                if words[0][0] == 'd':
                    dirs[words[-1]] = 0
                elif words[0][0] == '-':
                    files[words[-1]] = int(words[-5])
            return dirs, files
        except ftplib.all_errors:
            raise FTPStorageException('Error getting listing for %s' % path)

    def modified_time(self, name):
        self._start_connection()
        resp = self._connection.sendcmd('MDTM ' + name)
        if resp[:3] == '213':
            s = resp[3:].strip()
            # workaround for broken FTP servers returning responses
            # starting with e.g. 1904... instead of 2004...
            if len(s) == 15 and s[:2] == '19':
                s = str(1900 + int(s[2:5])) + s[5:]
            return datetime.strptime(s, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
        raise FTPStorageException(
                'Error getting modification time of file %s' % name
        )

    def listdir(self, path):
        self._start_connection()
        try:
            dirs, files = self._get_dir_details(path)
            return dirs.keys(), files.keys()
        except FTPStorageException:
            raise

    def delete(self, name):
        if not self.exists(name):
            return
        self._start_connection()
        try:
            self._connection.delete(name)
        except ftplib.all_errors:
            raise FTPStorageException('Error when removing %s' % name)

    def exists(self, name):
        self._start_connection()
        try:
            nlst = self._connection.nlst(
                os.path.dirname(name) + '/'
            )
            if name in nlst or os.path.basename(name) in nlst:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        except ftplib.error_temp:
            return False
        except ftplib.error_perm:
            # error_perm: 550 Can't find file
            return False
        except ftplib.all_errors:
            raise FTPStorageException('Error when testing existence of %s'
                                      % name)

    def size(self, name):
        self._start_connection()
        try:
            dirs, files = self._get_dir_details(os.path.dirname(name))
            if os.path.basename(name) in files:
                return files[os.path.basename(name)]
            else:
                return 0
        except FTPStorageException:
            return 0

    def url(self, name):
        if self._base_url is None:
            raise ValueError("This file is not accessible via a URL.")
        return urlparse.urljoin(self._base_url, name).replace('\\', '/')


class FTPStorageFile(File):
    def __init__(self, name, storage, mode):
        self.name = name
        self._storage = storage
        self._mode = mode
        self._is_dirty = False
        self.file = BytesIO()
        self._is_read = False

    @property
    def size(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_size'):
            self._size = self._storage.size(self.name)
        return self._size

    def read(self, num_bytes=None):
        if not self._is_read:
            self._storage._start_connection()
            self.file = self._storage._read(self.name)
            self._is_read = True

        return self.file.read(num_bytes)

    def write(self, content):
        if 'w' not in self._mode:
            raise AttributeError("File was opened for read-only access.")
        self.file = BytesIO(content)
        self._is_dirty = True
        self._is_read = True

    def close(self):
        if self._is_dirty:
            self._storage._start_connection()
            self._storage._put_file(self.name, self)
            self._storage.disconnect()
        self.file.close()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your import is wrong. If the file is named `ftp.py` the import should be:

```
from ftp import FTPStorage
```

Depending on where the file is relatively to your PYTHONPATH you might need to add more, e.g.:

```
from your_app.ftp import ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

#### models.py

```
from storages.backends.ftp import FTPStorage
fs = FTPStorage()
```

#### settings.py

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.ftp.FTPStorage'
FTP_STORAGE_LOCATION = 'ftp://user:password@localhost:21'
```