# Accessing sqlite database in Django project

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am newbie to Django, and following this SO question, I was able to create an application that helped me to upload an image to the server from the user end:

[Need a minimal Django file upload example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example)

However, I wish to access the database wherein the information about the updated files has been stored. Within the env and that directory, when I run sqlite>.database, I get the following output :

```
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main                                                                       
1    temp
```

I am not able to locate where my database has been stored, and how to access it. How do I get to access the database, and view it? ( so as to alter it)?

Comment: You should run ./manage.py dbshell.  Your database is stored in the location that you have set in setup.py