# django upload image file from templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

every one ,,I can upload image from admin site,, but do not know how to upload image from the templates,,

> models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
from django.utils import timezone



def get_imagep_Product(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['products', instance.slug, filename])


class ProductsTbl(models.Model):
    model_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    material = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    feature = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    release = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    submit_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_imagep_Product, blank=True) #image file 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''

        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        return super(ProductsTbl, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import ProductsTblForm
from .models import ProductsTbl
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import Http404,HttpResponse
import datetime

def create_thing(request):
    form_class = ProductsTblForm

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            thing = form.save(commit=False)

            thing.user = request.user
            thing.slug = slugify(thing.model_number)

            thing.save()

            return redirect('thing_detail', slug=thing.slug)

    else:
        form = form_class()
    return render(request, 'things/create_thing.html', { 'form': form,})
```

> urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from designer import views
from designer.backends import MyRegistrationView
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create_thing/$', views.create_thing, name='create_thing'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    ]
```

> forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import ProductsTbl


class ProductsTblForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductsTbl
        fields = ('model_number','name','feature', 'material','release','image',)
```

> create_thing.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block title %}
Create a Thing - {{ block.super }} {% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Create a Thing</h1>
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

when I click the create things I can see form here,,however I do not know how can let the image upload

[image]

I have looking for [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24066179/5678590) ,,however I do not know how to let it work in my app,,

Comment: Creating you form by `form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)` instead of `form_class(request.POST)` should be enough.

Comment: I add  request.FILES like ,,form = form_class(request.POST,request.FILES),,,but when I submit upload ,,there  is no image in midea/ ,,,??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>` definition. As this is required for file uploads.

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Second, instead of `form_class(request.POST)` you will need to create form in your view by passing `request.FILES` too.

```
form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
```