# django edit and upload image from templates

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

every one,,I have a template it can edit my data to database,however,when I try to upload an image from the templates ,,,just fail,,can any one tell me how can I code it and work well,thank you

> models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
from django.utils import timezone



def get_imagep_Product(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['products', instance.slug, filename])


class ProductsTbl(models.Model):
    model_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    material = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    feature = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    release = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    submit_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_imagep_Product, blank=True) #try to upload this image from templates

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''

        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        return super(ProductsTbl, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

....
```

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import ProductsTblForm,ProductsTblUploadForm
from .models import ProductsTbl,Upload
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import Http404,HttpResponse
import datetime
....
@login_required
def edit_thing(request, slug):
# grab the object...
    thing = ProductsTbl.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if thing.user != request.user:
        raise Http404
# set the form we're using...
    form_class = ProductsTblForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
# grab the data from the submitted form
        form = form_class(data=request.POST,instance=thing)
        if form.is_valid():
            # save the new data
            form.save()
            return redirect('thing_detail', slug=thing.slug)
# otherwise just create the form
    else:
        form = form_class(instance=thing)
# and render the template
    return render(request, 'things/edit_thing.html', {
        'thing': thing,
        'form': form,
    })
....
```

> urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from designer import views
from designer.backends import MyRegistrationView
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    ....
    url(r'^things/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit/$', views.edit_thing, name='edit_thing'),
    ....
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    ]
```

> forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import ProductsTbl,Upload


class ProductsTblForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductsTbl
        fields = ('model_number','name','feature', 'material','release','image',)
....
```

> edit_thing.html

```
....
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block title %}
Edit {{ thing.name }} - {{ block.super }} {% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Edit "{{ thing.name }}"</h1>
<form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}

<br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

<a href="{% url 'edit_thing_uploads' slug=thing.slug %}"> Edit images</a>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

when I create things ,,I can upload image just like [link here I asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36887400/5678590)

,however,,when I try to edit the form and upload an image just fail,,I do not know why?thank you

[image]

Comment: Define "just fail"

Comment: you mean the views.py?

Comment: ok,,I solve the problem,,views.py,,,,  form = form_class(data=request.POST,instance=thing) ---> form = form_class(data=request.POST,files=request.FILES,instance=thing) ,thank you

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem in `views.py`:

By changing following:

```
form = form_class(data=request.POST, instance=thing)
```

to:

```
form = form_class(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=thing)
```