# Django: object Id exists but the object has been deleted from media files

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am a newbie with Django trying a simple code to upload and delete a file. Following the instructions given at the accepted answer of [Need a minimal Django file upload example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example), I was able to create a successful version to upload a file. However, while trying to delete individual files, I did some blunder, and later fixed it.

The problem is that the files I deleted while testing the first version of deletion code  no longer exist as document files, but their IDs still exist somewhere in the memory (I can't figure out where). Although I managed to fix the code, I still get 'Delete' buttons next to the already deleted files (without names), and I can get document IDs when the user presses these buttons.

I have tried restarting the server and deleting the 'Media' folder from storage, but these buttons still exist. I still can't figure out where these reference IDs are stored. I just want a fresh version of the page to be launched without the buttons corresponding to already deleted files.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are stored in the database. You can access the database with `python manage.py dbshell`. If you haven't configured anything custom here it's probably SQLite. Here you can look up the correct table by entering `.tables`. Then you can use SQL to lookup and delete the model records which contain the non existing file references: `SELECT * FROM my_table;`, `DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = my_id;`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have Sqlite3 installed on my 64-bit system, so I installed SqliteBrowser to delete the records from the database.