# django ModelFormWithFileField, ModelWithFileField

Tags: python, django

I am trying to import ModelWithFileField without sucsess. 
here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/ it says to import in the following manner:

```
from .models import ModelWithFileField
```

this does not work for me, I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name ModelWithFileField
```

I have upgraded to the latest version of django

I get the same error when trying to do this:

```
from .forms import ModelFormWithFileField
```

Anyone out there know how to get these imports working?

Comment: It is not a django builtin. It is assumed that your forms.py has your custom form which is named `ModelFormWithFileField`

Comment: You may want to follow the example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8542030/2285236) as the example in the docs is not complete.

Answer (score 1):

No. That is an *example* of a model that contains a [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield). You need to use your own model.