# Django unable to show webpage

Tags: python, django

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvPKp.png)Trying to use Django 1.10 to create a file upload system (similar to this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example). My main problem is, no matter how hard I try, Django is unable to show my webpage (404 error). I have no idea why. I'm following the 1.9 example and it should be working, as far as I can tell. I've attached the error and my data tree

[image: error message]

```
[D:.
│   db.sqlite3
│   manage.py
│
├───.idea
│       courseworkupload.iml
│       misc.xml
│       modules.xml
│       workspace.xml
│
├───courseworkupload
│   │   settings.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   wsgi.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           settings.cpython-35.pyc
│           urls.cpython-35.pyc
│           wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│
├───upload
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   forms.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │   │   0001_initial.py
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   │           0001_initial.cpython-35.pyc
│   │           __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │
│   ├───templates
│   │       Final.html
│   │       upload.html
│   │
│   ├───uploadedfiles
│   └───__pycache__
│           admin.cpython-35.pyc
│           forms.cpython-35.pyc
│           models.cpython-35.pyc
│           urls.cpython-35.pyc
│           views.cpython-35.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│
├───Uploadedfiles
└───__pycache__
        manage.cpython-35.pyc][2]
```

**Views.py below**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .forms import docfieldform
from .models import Document



def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = docfieldForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document (docfile=request.FILES['newfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('upload'))
    else:
        form = docfieldform()

    return render( request,'Final.html',)
```

Comment: Link to image https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gIzy.png

Comment: In your url you missed the `.html` part. Should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/upload.html/`

Comment: @evansmurthi, Hi  attempted your changed still no luck.

Comment: same error or different error?

Comment: @evansmurithi Yeah exact same

Comment: Could you post your urls files i.e. the project url file and app url file

Comment: @evansmurithi Completed.

Comment: Remove the `.` from the url. It should be `r'^upload/$'`

Comment: @evansmurithi Thanks for that its now points to Final.html when it should be going to upload.html first any idea why that is?

Comment: Your upload view might be rendering `final.html` instead of `upload.html`. Kindly post the upload view.

Comment: @evansmurithi Completed.

Comment: Replace `render(request, 'Final.html')` with `render(request, 'upload.html')`

Comment: @evansmurithi That worked. Thank you!

Comment: Lemme post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `.html` in your URL conf so that it becomes `url(r'^upload/$', upload, name='upload')`. So if your browser url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/upload/` it should go to the `upload` view.

To display content in `upload.html` replace `render(request, 'Final.html')` with `render(request, 'upload.html')` in your upload view