# Do I need to handle uploaded files manually if I use a ModelForm?

Tags: django, file-upload, handle, modelform, imagefield

I have a model:

```
class Dialogue(models.Model):
    ...
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=conference_directory_path, blank=True)
    ...
```

And a ModelForm for it:

```
class CreateConferenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Dialogue
        fields = ['name', 'participants', 'avatar']
    ...
```

My question is do I need to make a special function for handle uploaded avatar like:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(file):
    with open(some_file_path, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chink in file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

Or I can without fear simply use save method of ModelForm? 
And if I can't - where is better place for this function: in view or in forms? And how does it look - saving an avatar using handle function? At the beggining I handle an uploaded file using handle function and then how can this uploaded file be added to imagefield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ModelForm will handle it for you, as long as your form uses `method="post"` and you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set on your form. You may also want to set `null=True` on the model field, otherwise the instance will not save when you don't provide an image.

Comment: Thank you. Therefore in usual Form I need to use handle function, right? If yes, could you please answer for the same questions about usual Form :)

Comment: @AlexanderShpindler here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example?rq=1