# Upload to rackspace with django

Tags: python, django, rackspace-cloud, rackspace, rackspace-cloudfiles

I have a image upload website :
I want to **upload my users photo(user upload image)** to [rackspace.com](http://www.rackspace.com)
But i dont have any information about upload to this site.
Tell me a way to upload my image to this server.

Comment: Rackspace is a cloud services provider. If you are using a cloudserver, and you would like to store images in the server storage, you could use the previous implementation you have for your old site.

Comment: How can i save image with useing server stronge?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871730/5476782) question.

Comment: I want to upload into rakespace not to my host!

Comment: Then you should explain better what you want, scenario, the code you already wrote, etc.

Comment: I explaned.read it!!!!

Comment: Try to make it understandable and write a good question as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
And maybe like that you will get help.