# Django retrieving submitted value from table

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a simple django project, with the following model:

```
class dealerinfo(models.Model):
         name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
         required_field_1 = models.ImageField()
         required_field_2= models.ImageField()
```

How to create a django app that after a user logs in to upload the required files required_field_1 and required_field_2.

Thank you for your suggestions and help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload a file in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/how-to-upload-a-file-in-django)

Comment: No, I know how to upload a file, I am trying to create an app that shows the user what required documents it needs to upload.

Comment: As in, making the fields `required=True` in a form, or `null=False, blank=False` in a model?

Comment: I will explain the process, a user simply registers and after he logs in, he goes to his profile section where it is prompted to him to upload the required documents.
And after he submits, it should say all required documents have been submitted.

Comment: I understand the concept/process, but I'm not sure what you're expecting from us? What problem are you having? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I created a normal forms.py and created appropriate pages and everything, I don't know how to implement this concept.
I am sorry, I am new to django.
I want to know how i can implement this. as right now it shows the upload file button and nothing else, it doesn't show that i have submitted the form or not.