# How to post pictures on django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-views

I have been trying to make my code able to post images but when I create the post, the picture doesnt appear but the image gets save on media/images I was wondering if there is any way to make the code work, ther might be something wrong in the base.html when I call the image {{ request.user.image.url }}

views.py

```
     def create(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            created_date = timezone.now()
            header1 = request.POST['header']
            content1 = request.POST['content']
            user = request.user
            uploded_file = request.FILES['image']
            created_obj = Create.objects.create(added_date=created_date, title=header1, content=content1, user=user, image=uploded_file)
            created_obj.save()
            print('create created')
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            print('create not created')
            return render(request, 'create.html')
```

models.py

```
    class Create(models.Model):
        added_date = models.DateTimeField()
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

create.html

```
    {% extends 'home.html' %}
    {% block body %}
    <div style="margin-top: 200px; margin-left:200px;">
        <form action="create" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="header" placeholder="Add here...">
            <input type="text" name="content" placeholder="Add here...">
            <input type="file" name="image">
            <button type="submit"name="action" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
    {% extends 'home.html' %}
    {% block body %}
    <ul action="{% url 'create' %}" class="container-sm list-group" style="margin-top: 200px;">
        {% for created_post in created_posts %}
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ created_post.title }}
          <a href="{% url 'profile_pk' pk=created_post.user.pk %}">{{ created_post.user }}</a>
          <img class="image" src="{{ create.image.url }}">
          <p>{{ created_post.content }}</p>
          <div class="float-right">
            <form action="delete_create/{{ created_post.id }}/" action="post">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="float-right">
            <a href="{% url 'edit' created_post.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm" style="margin-right: 5px;" role="button">Edit</a>
          </div>
        </li>     
        {% endfor %}            
    </ul>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: What's `context2` and where is its assignation?

Comment: take a look at [simple django file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24066179/). here is the live [demo](https://djangofileupload.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: sorry I that context 2 shouldnt be there