# Django when I upload a image is not saved

Tags: python, django, django-models, file-upload, django-views

I'm trying to create an auction system with django.

But when I create a new item for the auction, the image is not saved, but the rest of the item does. But the media folder isn't created.

**SETTINGS.PY**

```
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

**URLS.PY**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("core.urls")),
    path("users/", include("users.urls")),
    path("users/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path("auction/", include("auction.urls")),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    """
    With that Django's development server is capable of serving media files.
    """
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**MODELS.PY**

```
class Auction(models.Model):
    object = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, default="")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/", null=True, blank=True)
    open_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    close_date = models.DateTimeField()
    total_bet = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    open_price = models.FloatField(
        default=0,
    )
    close_price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    winner = models.CharField(max_length=256, default="")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    json_details_file = models.TextField(default="")
    tx = models.CharField(max_length=256, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.object
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Auction
        fields = ["object", "description", "image", "close_date", "open_price"]
        widgets = {
            "close_date": DateTimeInput(attrs={"placeholder": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM"})
        }
```

**VIEW.PY**

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def new_item(request):

    """
    A function that will create a new item for te auction
    """

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ItemForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Item create")
            return redirect("homepage")
    else:
        form = ItemForm()
    return render(request, "auction/new_item.html", {"form": form})
```

**new_item.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_superuser %}
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
        <div class="col-6 text-center">
            <h2>Creazione Item!</h2>
            <form class="" method="POST" novalidate>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info mt-4"  value="Crea Item">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <p>You arent' allowed</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I'd looked at every line of code and tried numerous times to upload the image but still not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload a file in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/how-to-upload-a-file-in-django)

Comment: See how form is declared in the template. Also media folder must be created beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your html form tag like so:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 1):

In your  tag use this `enctype="multipart/form-data"`