# How this code upload file in django can run the html file?

Tags: html, django, file, upload

The code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24066179/20933379)

I am confused about the html file, it looks like it was never called but it can be run and when I change upload_form.html name to upload.html, it could be an error. So how come? and how to make the program can run upload_form.html file in another name file?

This is my first question, so sorry if my question makes you confused >.<

I wish I could understand the code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code link you have attached is using one of Django's generic views `CreateView`. And Django follows some conventions to decide what template to use for the view. In the case of `CreateView` Django tries to find the template with the name of **model used by your view** in lowercase and the default `template_name_suffix` which is `_form`. In your case your model name is

```py
model = Upload
```

So Django tries to find a template with the name `upload_form.html`. And if you wish to change the default `template_name` you can always override it like this.

```py
class UploadView(CreateView):
    model = Upload
    template_name  = 'upload.html'
```

Besides this, you can also override the `get_template_names` method as well, it is sometimes useful when you have to conditionally decide the name of the template i.e you are planning to use a different HTML file for different users.
Here is the [Django docs link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) and another very [useful ref about CBVs](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.1/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/).