# Uploading file in django: only filename gets saved to DB, files dont appear in the media folder

Tags: python, django, django-media

I am new in Django. I am working on a project where user will able to add a file of type .doc, .img, .pdf, .csv.

Uploaded files are expected to be stored in media folder but they don't appear there.

Here is my code:

models.py

```
class Resources(models.Model):
    resource_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rec_file = models.FileField(upload_to = "resources/", max_length=10000, null=True, default=None)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py

```
def add_resources(request):
    title="Add Resources"
    requesturl = request.get_full_path
    title = 'Create Clinic'
    if request.method == "POST":
        resource_name = request.POST.get('resource_name')
        resource_file = request.POST.get('resource_file')
        resource_instances = Resources.objects.create(
            resource_name = resource_name,
            rec_file = resource_file
        )
        resource_instances.save()
            
    return render(request, 'add_resources.html',{'title':title, 'requesturl':requesturl})
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR/"media"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I upload the file it just saves the file name and nothing is saved in the media folder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/how-to-upload-a-file-in-django/8542030#8542030