# Django uploading an image with jquery - class based view

Tags: html, jquery, python-3.x, django, django-views

I want to save a model (Villa) in django with this form everغthing is ok but i don't know how to upload images with that when the villa is saved, it gets all its information, but saves the photos in a fake path that doesn't exist is there anyway to upload the image دn this method?

This is the code:

**HTML**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}Save Villa{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<script src="{% static 'assets/villa_save_form_check.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/villa_save_handle.js' %}"></script>
    <div class="container my-5 rounded-3 w-100 h-100 justify-content-center d-flex">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <form method="POST" class="form-control">
                    <h1 class="form-label">Villa</h1>
                    <hr>

                    <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" value="{{user.username}}">

                    <label class="form-label mt-1">Full Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="owner_id" id="owner_id" placeholder="Owner Name" class="form-control mb-2" required>

                    <label class="form-label mt-1">Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="number" oninput="phoneCheck()" name="phone_id" id="phone_id" placeholder="Owner Phone Number" class="form-control mb-2" required>

                    <label class="form-label mt-1">Price</label>
                    <input type="number" name="price_id" id="price_id" oninput="priceCheck()" placeholder="Villa Price" class="form-control mb-2" required>

                    <label class="form-label mt-1">Address</label>
                    <input type="url" name="address_id" id="address_id" placeholder="Villa Address" class="form-control mb-2" required>
                    
                    <label class="form-label mt-1">About</label>
                    <textarea name="description_id" id="description_id" oninput="descriptionCheck()" class="form-control mb-2" cols="100" rows="5" placeholder="Description" required></textarea>
                    
                    <label class="form-label mt-1">Title Image</label>
                    <input type="file" name="title_id" id="title_id" placeholder="Villa Address" class="form-control mb-2" required>
                    
                    <label class="form-label mt-1">Image 1</label>
                    <input type="file" name="img1_id" id="img1_id" placeholder="Villa Address" class="form-control mb-2" required>
                    
                    <label class="form-label mt-1">Image 2</label>
                    <input type="file" name="img2_id" id="img2_id" placeholder="Villa Address" class="form-control mb-2" required>
                    
                    <label class="form-label mt-1">Image 3</label>
                    <input type="file" name="img3_id" id="img3_id" placeholder="Villa Address" class="form-control mb-2" required>
                    
                    <label class="form-label mt-3">Save</label>
                    <input type="submit" onmouseover="finalCheck()" name="btn_save_id" id="btn_save_id" data-csrftoken="{{csrf_token}}" placeholder="Villa Address" class="btn btn-outline-success form-control mb-2" required>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

jQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  $('#btn_save_id').click(function (e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();


    var csrf_token = $(this).data('csrftoken');
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var owner = $('#owner_id').val();
    var phone = $('#phone_id').val();
    var price = $('#price_id').val();
    var address = $('#address_id').val();
    var description = $('#description_id').val();
    var title_IMG = $('#title_id').val();
    var img1 = $('#img1_id').val();
    var img2 = $('#img2_id').val();
    var img3 = $('#img3_id').val();

    $.ajax({
      url: '/owner/panel/create_villa/',
      type: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token
      },
      data: {
        'username': username,
        'owner': owner,
        'phone': phone,
        'price': price,
        'address': address,
        'description': description,
        'title_IMG': title_IMG,
        'img1': img1,
        'img2': img2,
        'img3': img3,
      },
      success: function (response)
      {
        alert('Villa saved successfully\nYour villa will be visible as soon as it is verified by admin');
        $('#username').val('');
        $('#owner_id').val('');
        $('#phone_id').val('');
        $('#price_id').val('');
        $('#address_id').val('');
        $('#description_id').val('');
        $('#title_id').val('');
        $('#img1_id').val('');
        $('#img2_id').val('');
        $('#img3_id').val('');
      },
      error: function (xhr)
      {
        console.log('Error:', xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

View:

```
class OwnerVillaCreatePanel(CreateView):
    model = Villa
    template_name = 'owner_villa_creation.html'
    fields = "__all__"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        print('\n\n\n-----------------------------------\n\n\n')
        print('OwnerVillaCreatePanel View POST method called')
        print('\n\n\n-----------------------------------\n\n\n')

        rq_username = request.POST["username"]
        owner = request.POST["owner"]
        phone = request.POST["phone"]
        price = request.POST["price"]
        address = request.POST["address"]
        description = request.POST["description"]
        title_IMG = request.POST["title_IMG"]
        img1 = request.POST["img1"]
        img2 = request.POST["img2"]
        img3 = request.POST["img3"]

        newVilla = Villa(
            username = User.objects.get(username=rq_username),
            villa_owner = owner,
            villa_contact = phone,
            villa_price = price,
            villa_id = "000000",
            villa_rate = "1",
            villa_address = address,
            villa_description = description,
            description_img1 = title_IMG,
            description_img2 = img1,
            description_img3 = img2,
            description_img4 = img3,
            likes = 0,
            verified = False,
        )

        newVilla.save()

        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Model:

```
class Villa(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=False, null=True, verbose_name="Username")
    villa_owner = models.CharField("Owner", null=False, blank=False, default="ADD OWNER PLEASE", max_length=75, unique=False, help_text="Owner name")
    villa_contact = models.CharField("Phone Number", null=False, blank=False, max_length=11, default="09991112233", help_text="Visitors will call this number")
    villa_price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Price", blank=False, null=False, default=0, help_text="ریال")
    villa_id = models.CharField("ID", max_length=6, blank=False, null=False, help_text="Villa ID")
    villa_rate = models.CharField("Rate", max_length=1, blank=False, null=False, help_text="1-5", default=1)
    villa_address = models.URLField("Address", blank=False, null=False, help_text="Villa Address", max_length=254, unique=True)
    villa_description = models.TextField("About", max_length=800, null=True, blank=True, help_text="About the villa")
    description_img1 = models.ImageField("Image-1", upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True, default="images/default_img.jpg")
    description_img2 = models.ImageField("Image-2", upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True, default="images/default_img.jpg")
    description_img3 = models.ImageField("Image-3", upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True, default="images/default_img.jpg")
    description_img4 = models.ImageField("Image-4", upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True, default="images/default_img.jpg")
    slug = models.SlugField("Slug", editable=False, max_length=180, unique=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField("Liked", default=0)
    verified = models.BooleanField("Visible", default=False, blank=False, null=False, help_text="shown in main page if true")
    user_likes: list = []
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "Villa-{}  |  Owner: {}".format(self.villa_id, self.villa_owner)

    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = "villa_{}".format(self.villa_id)
        if int(self.villa_rate) > 5 or int(self.villa_rate) < 1:
            self.villa_rate = str(1)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def like_villa(self, username: any):
         if username not in self.user_likes:
            self.likes += 1
            self.user_likes.append(username)
            self.save()
         else:
            self.likes -= 1
            self.user_likes.remove(username)
            self.save()
        
    def is_verifid(self) -> bool:
        if self.verified:
            return True
        return False
```

URL path:

```
path('owner/panel/create_villa/', login_required(OwnerVillaCreatePanel.as_view(), login_url="login"), name="owner_create_villa_panel"),
```

Comment: Please reduce the code so it can be called a _minimal_ repro; also non-english letters which look like typos better would be fixed. Please bring more focus to your question, point to specific problem, add error traceback or other debugging details. It's currently unclear whether you're getting any exceptions or not, what is a "fake path". And there are so many answered questions about uploading files with Django/JQuery on SO, please use search.

Comment: See item 7 here, `<form>` tag declaration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/how-to-upload-a-file-in-django/8542030#8542030