# Django: automatically import MEDIA_URL in context

Tags: python, django

like exposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433162/can-i-access-constants-in-settings-py-from-templates-in-django/433255#433255), one can set a MEDIA_URL in settings.py (for example i'm pointing to Amazon S3) and serve the files in the view via `{{ MEDIA_URL }}`. Since MEDIA_URL is not automatically in the context, one have to manually add it to the context, so, for example, the following works:

```
#views.py

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def test(request):
    return render_to_response('test.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This means that in each view.py file i have to add `from django.template import RequestContext` and in each response i have to explicitly specify `context_instance=RequestContext(request)`.

Is there a way to automatically (DRY) add MEDIA_URL to the default context? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a generic view for this use :

```
direct_to_template(request, template, extra_context=None, mimetype=None, **kwargs)
```

It is not well documented (in my opinion : it doesn't tell that it uses a `RequestContext`), so I advise you to check out the implementation :

http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/views/generic/simple.py

I think it is what you are looking for ...

Comment: I use this thing instead of render_to_template

Comment: thanks, that is what i was looking for. it should be more evident in the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Add `"django.core.context_processors.media"` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in the settings file.