# How to debug Django i18n?

Tags: django, internationalization

I have inherited a Django project that needs i18n. I have done all the usual actions required for i18n that I usually do in other projects and that usually work. But on this one it was not working, it's Django 1.3 so I went to the docs on i18n and followed all the steps and yet it's not working.

I don't know what could have gone wrong, since I did not set up all the project myself I don't know which part of it could break i18n.

In base.html I added the typical language select from the docs + the LANGUAGE_CODE tag to get some feedback:

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
<select name="language">
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
{% for language in languages %}
<option value="{{ language.code }}">{{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
Lang:{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Whatever I do, the LANGUAGE_CODE always returns the default en-us or whatever I set in settings.

In which order should I check things? Where to start, what to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#language-code), LANGUAGE_CODE is set to the installation language code. Are you sure you've changed it from en-us in your settings file?

Have you tried printing the language code out at the end of your settings file and then running in a non-deamon mode so you can see it's output? Personally, I use multi-part configuration files and have previously had issues where latter settings files have altered something I expected to work further down the line. Is that a possibility?

If it looks right at the end of the settings file then it's probably not being fed through to the template properly. You could try pushing it through yourself like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/433255/15369) to be sure.

One other thing to check; are you sure it's not settings.LANGUAGE_CODE you need? I can't remember whether that's just in the model off the top of my head.

Comment: I tried with and without LANGUAGE_CODE, with runserver, with Apache, daemon and non daemon...

Comment: What did printing out the value at the end of the settings give you?

Comment: but thanks for the mutli settings file idea, I thought they were clean but discovered some horrors there just right now and the locale middleware was not imported! i18n now works :) I'm going to clean that right away.