# How do I get Django to recognize a custom template tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

My project directory looks like this.  `settings_value.py` has a template tag, named 'settings_value' in it.  In my settings.py I added 'itslogical.templatetags' to `INSTALLED_APPS`.  I try to use it in `logicalhp/home.html`, but it says the tag doesn't exist.  I'm using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5235614/1074592) (I changed the name from 'value_from_settings' to 'settings_value').

```
.
├── internetparse
│   └── ...
├── itslogical
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── itslogical
│   │       └── base.html
│   └─── templatetags
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── settings_value.py
├── logicalhp
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── logicalhp
│   │       └── home.html
│   └── views.py
└── manage.py
```

Let me know if you need anything else.  What am I missing here?

Edit: added code and updated error.  This is based on @Dan's answer.

```
500 ERROR:
'settings_value' is not a valid tag library: Template library settings_value not found
Template library settings_value not found, tried django.templatetags.settings_value ...
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from django import template
from django.conf import settings

# Include settings from here in templates
register = template.Library()

# settings value
@register.tag
def settings_value(parser, token):
    try:
        # split_contents() knows not to split quoted strings.
        tag_name, var = token.split_contents()
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError, "%r tag requires a single argument" % token.contents.split()[0]
    return ValueFromSettings(var)

class ValueFromSettings(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.arg = template.Variable(var)

    def render(self, context):
        return settings.__getattr__(str(self.arg))
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add the templatetags directory to installed apps. You should put the templatetags directory inside an existing app, and add that to installed apps.

Comment: I moved it, and updated the question.  The error is weird, so maybe I did something wrong in the code...

Answer (score 1):

Try to move templatetags folder to logicalhp

Comment: Thanks.  That's the first problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem was a typo in my settings.py (wrote the 'logicalhp.templatetags' when it was in 'itslogical').  The larger problem was that it was trying to get the attribute `"STATIC_URL"` from my settings.  It included the quotes, so it was effectively `settings.__getattr__('"STATIC_URL"')`.

To fix it, I added a strip.

```
return settings.__getattr__(str(self.arg)) #before
return settings.__getattr__(str(self.arg).strip('"')) #after
```

(By the way, it's not like you can omit the quotes in the template; else it think's its a variable. )