# How would you go about creating a "config" class in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, config

I'm making a very very reusable CMS in Django. I'm trying not to hardcode anything, so I want a config.py or something for the app itself.

I want to use it in templates (something like {{ config.SITE_NAME }}) and just regular Python code (views, models), etc.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

Django already has the settings.py file and an interface to use the values from there, is that not good enough? Accessing settings in your code is easy:

```
from django.conf import settings
do_something_with(settings.MY_CONFIG_VARIABLE)
```

In your template it requires a bit more work, like making a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) for example. This answer shows you have to make [a context processor that exposes values from settings to your template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/433209/1220555).

Answer (score 1):

settings.py serves this purpose already in django.  You can add custom settings to it for your application.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code

Answer (score -1):

When you create a django project, it automatically creates a `settings.py` file. Put your settings in that file, and then :-

```
from django.conf import settings  
settings.YOUR_SETTING
```

also, if you have some settings, that will vary depending upon the machines (eg. production/test servers).
Then just add eg. `conf/local_settings.py` file and put the machine specific settings in that file, and in `settings.py` just do :-

```
from conf.local_settings import *
```

at the end of `settings.py`
Make sure you ignore `local_settings.py` from your VCS check-in (eg. in case of git add `local_settings.py` to `.gitignore`

Comment: Instead of the local_settings.py convention, you might recommend things like server specific settings, use of environment variables, or  tools like django-configurations.

Comment: correct!, my personal recommendation would have been http://zookeeper.apache.org/ , but depends upon need.