# Getting admin email(s) from Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Is there a way to access the `ADMINS` variable of the `settings` module from an any arbitrary template without adding manually adding it into the context before being rendered, similar to how `request` is available in any template using `RequestContext` if `django.core.context_processors.request` is in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`?

Comment: Just pass it to your template from a view.

Answer (score 6):

You can write your own context processor (which is a regular function that has `request` as parameter):

```
from django.conf import settings

def admin_emails(request):
    return { 'ADMINS': settings.ADMINS }
```

and add `path.to.my.context_processor.admin_emails` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a template tag like discussed for this question:
[Can I access constants in settings.py from templates in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433162/can-i-access-constants-in-settings-py-from-templates-in-django)

Specifically I use the code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343321/2250326

With that you can get at the AMDINS in your templates like this:

```
{% value_from_settings "ADMINS" as admins %}
{% for admin in admins %}
    Name: {{ admin.0 }}<br />
    Email: {{ admin.1 }}
{% endfor %}
```