# Accessing variables in setting.py from templates with Django 1.4

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, requestcontext

I'd like to load the site name in a template using:

```
{{ SITE_NAME }}
```

In `setting.py` I have:

```
SITE_NAME = "MySite"
```

and

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as TCP

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

I'm also using Class Based Views to load my view (`views.py`):

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class MenuNavMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MenuNavMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context


class AboutView(MenuNavMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "home/about.html"
```

`urls.py`:

```
url(r'^about/$', AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
```

I can't access `SITE_NAME` in `home/about.html` unless I specifically add it to the context variables with:

```
import mywebsite.settings

class MenuNavMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MenuNavMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['SITE_NAME'] = mywebsite.settings.SITE_NAME
        return context
```

I thought that this wasn't the case if I used:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: My previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433162/can-i-access-constants-in-settings-py-from-templates-in-django/7716141#7716141

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django.core.context_processors.request` only adds the request to the context, see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).

Write your won context processor, something like:

```
from django.conf import settings    

def add_site_setting(request):
  return {'site_name': settings.SITE_NAME}
```

Then add that function to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your settings.py

Also, I suggest a good habit to get into is using `from django.conf import settings` rather than explicitly importing your settings file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what gave you that impression. The `request` context processor does exactly what it says on the tin: adds the *request* to the context processor. There's nothing that says it will do anything with the SITE_NAME setting - especially as that isn't even a standard setting.

If you want that to be added by a context processor, then you can write your own - it'll only be two lines of code.