# add variables in settings to be used in views - Django

Tags: python, django, django-settings

```
def get(self , request , format=None):
    body = request.data
    name = body.get('name',"The_Flash")
```

In this instance I have hardcoded the value *The_Flash* if the request.data receives no value for **name** , but I know this is not a sound way. I want this to be added as a variable in the settings.py file of my django project. I went through references from SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433162/can-i-access-constants-in-settings-py-from-templates-in-django) and few others but this is not what I want. Can someone tell me which is the most robust way of doing this. I am using Django 1.8.

Comment: Can you please explain why you think this is not ' a sound way' to do this? Isnt this approach more readable than accessing a constant?

Comment: Hardcoding things is not a correct way. This may not be the only instance where i need it. If I keep things hardcoded , in case I want to change that hardcoded value I will have to change from every instance which maynot be feasible if I am working with lots of such instances.

Comment: How about this approach https://gist.github.com/aswinpj/baf79d2f1ff212b8552d7164ce1bd5a5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We tend to store settings variables in a module in the app called `app_settings.py`, and use this to set defaults for settings and allow the user to override them in Django's `settings.py`:

```
# app_settings.py
from django.conf import settings

MY_SETTING = getattr(settings, 'APP_NAME_MY_SETTING', 'the_default_value')
```

Then import this in your views and use it:

```
# views.py
from app_settings import MY_SETTING
```

And users can override it in their project settings:

```
# project's settings.py
APP_NAME_MY_SETTING = 'something else'
```

This allows you to change it per deployment, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can store constants in a seperate file and import it into your project

folder/

```
appconfigurations.py
views.py
```

appconfigurations.py

```
YOUR_CONSTANT = "constant_value"
```

views.py

```
from appconfigurations import *

def your_view(request):
    constant = YOUR_CONSTANT
```

Answer (score 0):

In views.py file:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.Variable_Name
```