# Not able to serve media files in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create an online music player. I was trying to play a song in django. But it was not able to play since it was not able to detect the audio file. I have set up the media in django as I read on the internet but it's not working.

Here is the screenshot of my project directory:

[image]
detect and music are two apps. I am currently working with music app.

Settings.py(included this at last of file).

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.contrib import admin
from detect import views
from music import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^music/$',views.play,name = 'play')

]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
def play(request):
    return render(request,'music/song.html',{})
```

song.html:

```
<html>
<audio id="Player" autoplay>
     <source src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/audio/test.mp3"/>
</audio>
</html>
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/433255/378704) might help

Comment: @kiran.koduru I am not sending a song from view. So that doesn't help.

Comment: If you referred to that answer then you will see you need to pass a variable to your template to access `MEDIA_URL`. So you can pass `MEDIA_URL` like this `render(request,'music/song.html',{'MEDIA_URL': settings.MEDIA_URL})`

Comment: @kiran.koduru Thanks,that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `MEDIA_URL` like to `render` like this
`render(request,'music/song.html',{'MEDIA_URL': settings.MEDIA_URL})` and make sure to include `from django.conf import settings` in your `views.py`.