# Django registration of tag library not working

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I try to register my custom template tag library in django, but unfortunately it isnt working!

I want to create a custom include-tag and followed the instruction at:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags-inclusion-tags

I have created an app called 'tag_lib' (installed in settings.py) to put my template tags in. In the app folder is a dictionary called 'templatetags' containing an empty `__init__.py` and my `my_tags.py`.

`my_tags.py` contains:

```
from django import template


register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag(filename='navbar.html', takes_context=True)
def navbar_context(context):
    return {
        'some_var': context['some_var'],
    }
```

When I restart my devserver and try to load the library with

```
{% load my_tags %} `
```

in a template, I'm getting the error:`

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /

'my_tags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
staticfiles
tz
```

Any idea where I made a mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: The app must be in your settings.INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: It is installed in the settings.py! I checked that first. I did everything what is marked in the doc or suggested in other questions!

Comment: Your error message has my_tag whereas your `{% load my_tags %}`. Note the s at the end of tag.  You may have added/not added it where required?

Comment: Thank you, it was a spelling mistake in my question, I edited it. Unfortunately I did it right in my code :|

Comment: Try moving your `templatetags` directory out of `tag_lib` and into your "primary app" (whatever it is called) directory.  That'll show you if it is something wrong with how you've set up `tag_lib`

Comment: You don't seem to missing any step.  However, you didn't mention that tag_lib directory contains a `__init.py__` script. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tried to set it up in my main app before, the result is the same. I set up my tag_lib with the startapp command in manage.py so its set-up properly with __init__.py and everything else....

Comment: Ok, can you fire a django shell and import your `my_tags` module ? `./manage.py shell`, then `from tag_lib.templatetags import my_tags`. It might be that for some reason (syntax error or whatever) your module triggers an `ImportError`...

Comment: I can acces my tag library via django shell, no errors are raised... That's why I am so confused about what is going wrong... I will now set up a new django project to check if it's my current project which is faulty...

Comment: try restarting your `runserver`

Answer (score 21):

I faced this problem to.what i did was just stop the server run and just run it again.It seems that django does not initialize tags (or resources in general) while running the server.hope it helps.

Answer (score 9):

According to django documentation:

> **Development server won’t automatically restart** after adding the templatetags module, you will need to restart your server before you can use the tags or filters in templates.

So, to resolve the issue, you need restart development server.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout

Answer (score 2):

Just for a reminder, when using django under Windows, it is necessary to restart the development server (python.exe manage.py runserver) in at least two situations, which are:

- when a new templatetag was created in an app
- when static files were modified in the 'app/static/app/' folder

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, but reloading the server doesn't work.
So I solved it by this:

at project/setting.py I wrote the next, at TEMPLATE I registered libraries:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
        'libraries': {
            'my_tags': 'app.templatetags.blog_tags',
        }
    },
},
```

]

And the server restarted by itself.

Comment: This has worked for me.. using Django v3.2.16

Answer (score 0):

In Django 3.1 i solved it putting my py file inside templatetags folder inside my app. As the docs said. [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/).
The py file must have register = template.Library()

myapp/templatetags/mytags.py

in settings i have myapp inside INSTALLED_APPS array

Then in my template file

```
{% load mytags %}
```