# Unable to register django custom template tags

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I want to register 3 custom template tags and show the info they generate in all the pages of my project. I have [read the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) and created the following files:

`blog_tags.py`

```py
from django import template
from django.db.models import Count
from ..models import Post

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def total_posts():
    return Post.published.count()


@register.inclusion_tag("blog/post/latest_posts.html")
def show_latest_posts(count=5):
    latest_posts = Post.published.order_by("-publish")[:count]
    return {"latest_posts": latest_posts}


@register.simple_tag
def get_most_commented_posts(count=5):
    return Post.published.annotate(total_comments=Count("comments")).order_by(
        "-total_comments"
    )[:count]
```

And my template: `base.html`

```html
{% load static %}
{% load blog_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>
      {% block title %}{% endblock %}
    </title>
    <link href="{% static "css/blog.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="content">
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <h2>
        My blog</h2>
      <p>
        This is my blog. I've written
        {% total_posts %}
        posts so far.</p>
      <h3>
        Latest posts</h3>
      {% show_latest_posts 3 %}
      <h3>
        Most commented posts</h3>
      {% get_most_commented_posts as most_commented_posts %}
      <ul>
        {% for post in most_commented_posts %}
          <li>
            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
              {{ post.title }}
            </a>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

However, the tags are not getting loaded. The page does not open. Instead, I get the following error: `Invalid block tag on line 3: 'total_posts'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?` As you can see, I do have loaded my tags with `{% load blog_tags %}` so I don't understand what is wrong.

This is the folder structure of my code:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265564/django-registration-of-tag-library-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [Django's Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) `Development server won’t automatically restart`.

So restarting your development server will solve your problem.