# Best practice to display Celery tasks activity to front end user in Django

Tags: python, django, celery

What is the best practice to display information to the user during and at the end of a celery task?
My users have the ability to generate Celery tasks via forms, I would like to give them access to a listview where they can see what the tasks as done, generated during the execution of the tasks and if it's finished.
Do I have to generate a table in my database with this information to be able to display them? I would like to use something like [django-loger-viewer](https://pypi.org/project/django-log-viewer/) but for front-end user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django celery worker to send real-time status and result messages to front end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47841809/django-celery-worker-to-send-real-time-status-and-result-messages-to-front-end)